# Changes to formatted contenteditable div

Tags: jquery

I have the following
Step 1. An editable div where one can type some text. 
Step 2. I click on colorize words and all of the words in the editable div are wrapped in spans each with a unique id. 
Step 3. I can select 5 different colours and click on each span to make it that colour (adding a class to the span).

Now i can choose to save the colour formatted text.

However i also have a button called "edit text". Clicking this button i'm able to edit the text again.

But my question is then how do i make jquery remember which words i have coloured?

An example where i write:

I am a happy man.

I click "colorize" and the editable div becomes non-editable and the 5 colours are shown. 
I select a green color and click on "happy". 
I click on a red color and click on "man". 
I now have the following html inside the div:

```
 <span id=1>I</span>
 <span id=2>am</span>
 <span id=3>a</span>
 <span id=4 class=green>happy</span>
 <span id=5 class=red>man</span>
```

So now i want to edit the text (clicking the "edit text" button)

So i alter the text to:

I am a very happy man

I then click "colorize" and would expect:

```
 <span id=1>I</span>
 <span id=2>am</span>
 <span id=3>a</span>
 <span id=6>very</span>
 <span id=4 class=green>happy</span>
 <span id=5 class=red>man</span>
```

How can i achieve this?
Or if i delete one of the words i want the span tags to go away?

I've been struggling quite some time with this issue, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid this is going to be quite complicated. You could remember based off the word in an object, but that'd mean every instance of this word would have this color.
Maybe something like this ...

```
var wordColors = {};
var colorWord = function (word, color) {
  span.css('color', color);
  wordColors[word] = color;
}
var onEditEnd = function () {
  // process spans etc
  var c;
  for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; ++i) {
    if (c = wordColors[span.innerHTML])
      span.css('color', c);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a try. Would it be easier to add a .bind onchange to each of the words which has a class? To check if its content is empty and then delete its parent span tag?

Comment: If you allow to edit the text as a whole, the spans are just going to get deleted

Comment: If i only delete the content of a span i need to hit delete an extra time to remove the span :( if i simply delete the text and type something else at the same place it will have the old span element.

Comment: In this case yes. If you edit the text as a sentence it won't work